# method to delete all nodes with a value x, c++, double linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I have 2 methods in my program, one finds the node with the value x and another one deletes the node with that value. Here they are:

```
node*findNode(int x)
{
    for (node*p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        if (p->data == x) 
        {
            return p;
        }
    }
    return NULL;

}

void removeNode(node*tmp)
{
    if (tmp == NULL)
    {
    }
    else if (tmp == head)
        removeFront();
    else if (tmp == tail)
        removeBack();
    else {
        tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
        tmp->prev->next =tmp->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

void remove(int x)
{
    node*tmp = findNode(x);
    removeNode(tmp);
}
```

I know my removeFront and removeBack methods work well. My question is,how could I implement it so instead of deleting only one node with x, it deletes all nodes that contain x in the list. I tried to implement another for loop inside findNode but it didn't work. I am not even sure I can do that.

```
node*findNode(T x)
{
    for (node*p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        if (p->data == x) 
        {
            node*z = p;
            return p;

            for (node*i = z->next; i != NULL; i = i->next)
            {
                if (i->data == x)
                    return i;
            }
            return NULL;
        }

    }
    return NULL;

}
```

My idea was to have a pointer after we find the first value and then do the same process but it didn't work.

So basically if list contains: 10 20 30 30 40 50  , and I use remove(30) it should delete all 30's

Comment: The inner `for` loop will never be executed since it's after a `return` statement

Comment: Also you cannot return more than 1 value from a function, so you need to return some sort of collection holding all the `node*` your function finds

Comment: thank you, at least you were not arrogant as the ones that just say my post doesn't show any effort :)

Answer (score 1):

You need a loop inside of `remove()`:

```
void remove(int x)
{
    node *p = head;
    while (p)
    {
        node *next = p->next;
        if (p->data == x)
            removeNode(p);
        p = next;
    }
}
```

On a side note: I wouldn't separate `removeNode()` the way you have. It makes more sense to keep all of the update operations in a single method, eg:

```
void removeNode(node *tmp)
{
    if (!tmp) return;
    if (tmp->next) tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
    if (tmp->prev) tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
    if (tmp == head) head = tmp->next;
    if (tmp == tail) tail = tmp->prev;
    delete tmp;
}
```

Then you can implement the other methods in terms of `removeNode()`:

```
void removeFront()
{
    removeNode(head);
}

void removeBack()
{
    removeNode(tail);
}
```